# Making buttons equally sized based on biggest button in HTML form

Tags: css, forms

In the code sample below I have a simple form with two submit buttons.

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" value="< Previous">
    <input type="submit" value="Next >">
</form>
```

Depending on the `value` attribute the buttons will get different sizes, like the image below:

[image]

Is there a method I can use to make the buttons equally sized based on the widest button? I use Bootstrap if that's any advantage...

I know that I *could* use a fix CSS-`width` (or similar) to set equal widths on the buttons. But since I don't know how wide the `value` will be in advance it won't solve the problem... (or will it?).

Comment: I don't think this is possible with just CSS. Flexbox can make both buttons the same size - but can't set the smaller button to the exact size of the larger button (such that the larger button shrinks to fit) - https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/Bdvmwd

Answer (score 1):

Use **JQuery**

```
var prev = $('#prev').width();
var next = $('#next').width();
if (prev > next) {
  $('#next').width(prev);
} else {
  $('#prev').width(next);
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/owm4x1jn/1/) I made..